# Implementing custom Subject<T, E> in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I have a `PublishSubject` that receive `String`s and emit `Article`s

```
private PublishSubject<String> articleSubject;

public Observable<Article> newArticleSubject() {
    articleSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    return articleSubject.flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Article>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Article> call(String articleId) {
            return dataModel.getArticleById(articleId);
        }
    });
}

articleSubject.onNext("1234");
```

I'd like to create a class `ArticleSubject` extending `Subject<String, Article>` that encapsulate this behaviour. I have tried this:

```
public class ArticleSubject extends Subject<String, Article> {

    private PublishSubject<String> subject;

    protected ArticleSubject(OnSubscribe<Article> articleOnSubscribe, final IMainDataModel dataModel) {
        super(articleOnSubscribe); //<---- ?????
        this.subject = PublishSubject.create();
        this.subject.flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Article>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Article> call(String s) {
                return dataModel.getArticleById(s);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasObservers() {
        return subject.hasObservers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        subject.onCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        subject.onError(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        subject.onNext(s);
    }
}
```

But, what to do with the `OnSubscribe` in the constructor? Do I have to mantain the subscribers and all that stuff? Is there a way to delegate that to the `PublishSubject`?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem - what are you trying to solve by using Subjects?

Comment: I want a subject that when receives a String (`subject.onNext("1")`), it emits a `Article`.

Comment: Yes, that was pretty clear from the original question. However, that in itself is the Y to "I want to do X, and I can do it via Y". Why specifically do you need a Subject? Why can't you have an Observable chain?

Comment: If you really want to do this with subjects, [here](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2015/09/subjects-part-2.html) is my blog post about how to create custom `Subject`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a generic solution:

```
public abstract class SubjectBinding<T, E> implements Observer<T> {

    private PublishSubject<T> origin;

    public SubjectBinding() {
        this.origin = PublishSubject.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        origin.onCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        origin.onError(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T t) {
        origin.onNext(t);
    }

    public Observable<E> asObservable() {
        return origin.flatMap(new Func1<T, Observable<E>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<E> call(T t) {
                return asObservable(t);
            }
        });
    }

    protected abstract Observable<E> asObservable(T t);

}
```

and

```
 private class ArticleSubject extends SubjectBinding<String, Article> {
        @Override
        protected Observable<Article> asObservable(String s) {
            return dataModel.getArticleById(s);
        }
    }
```

Now, I can send `String` values:

```
articleSubject.onNext("1234");
```

and it emits `Article`s:

```
public Observable<Article> newArticleSubject() {
    return new ArticleSubject().asObservable();
}
```